# How to have branching fetch conditions on while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have the same large block of code for a while loop whose condition requires fetch_assoc() on a MySqli connection but fetch() on a PDO connection. I want to remove the redundancy of including the same block of code twice. Written out in the long form, it takes this shape:

```
if ($connection_type == 'mysqli')   
    while ($row = $resultObject->fetch_assoc()) {
        [big routine]
    }

} elseif ($connection_type == 'pdo') {
    while ($row = $resultObject->fetch()) { 
        [same big routine]
    }
}
```

I've discovered that I can, in fact, combine the conditions, but only because I only have 2 connection possibilities currently (MySqli and PDO), so this is not ideal if--somehow--I should wish in the future to use a third connection condition:

```
while (($connection_type == 'mysqli') ? $row = $resultObject->fetch_assoc() : $row = $resultObject->fetch()) {
    [big routine]
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there an unobvious pitfall to this solution? What about cases involving more than 2 different connection conditions (I'm looking down the road here, obviously.)

Comment: Just curious.. is there a compelling reason for not using PDO for your mysql connection?

Comment: Because my current database is MySQL, MySQLi (which apparently runs faster than PDO) would be sufficient, but in case I migrate to another server with a different database type, I want PDO in place so I don't have to rewrite the queries at that time. At present, I can use a switch to go between the two, but I default it to MySQLi.

Comment: Same technique I used to abstract away the differences between the two different result object can also be done on the connection classes.

Answer (score 3):

In my option the easiest way to deal with this would be to abstract away the differences between the two apis.

Something like:

```
<?php
interface DBResult {
    public function fetch();
}

class MysqliDbResult implements DBResult {
    private $stmt;
    public function __construct(mysqli_stmt $stmt){
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }

    public function fetch(){
        return $this->stmt->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
class PdoDbResult implements DBResult {
    private $stmt;
    public function __construct(PDOStatement $stmt){
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }

    public function fetch(){
        return $this->stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate a new typed result from a database connection you can wrap it in an appropriate implemention of DBResult.

```
// is resultObject pdo or mysqli .... I don't care ...
while ($row = $resultObject->fetch()) { 
    [same big routine]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect use case for the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). You would create a class that has a fetch method that acts like an adapter to an internal mysqli or PDO instance. You could also do it with a function as a one-off.

```
function fetch($resultObject, $connection_type) {
    switch ($connection_type) {
        case 'mysqli':
            return $resultObject->fetch_assoc();
        case 'pdo':
            return $resultObject->fetch();
        case '....':
            //more cases
    }
}

while ($row = fetch($resultObject, $connection_type)) { 
    big_routine($row);
}
```